# Modifying each word of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

So, what I'm trying to do is create a function that allows the user to input a string and then it will output the string in pig latin. Here's my function now:

```
function wholePigLatin() {
            var thingWeCase = document.getElementById("isLeaper").value;
            thingWeCase = thingWeCase.toLowerCase();
            var newWord = (thingWeCase.charAt(0));

            if (newWord.search(/[aeiou]/) > -1) {
                alert(thingWeCase + 'way')
            } else {
                var newWord2 = thingWeCase.substring(1, thingWeCase.length) + newWord + 'ay';
                alert(newWord2)
            }
        }
```

How do I get it so that it recognizes each word and then modifies each word the way that I have above?

Comment: if it is just simple string then i think you need to split the string based on spaces==>.split(' ');

Answer (score 1):

Modify the function to take an argument and return the value

```
function wholePigLatin(thingWeCase) {
    thingWeCase = thingWeCase.toLowerCase();
    var newWord = (thingWeCase.charAt(0));

    if (newWord.search(/[aeiou]/) <= -1) {
       newWord = thingWeCase.substring(1, thingWeCase.length) + newWord + 'ay';
    }
    else{
       newWord = thingWeCase + 'way';
    }
    return newWord;
}
```

then you can do this:

```
var pigString = str.split(" ").map(wholePigLatin).join(" ");
```

That will split the string into words, pass each word to the function, and then join the outputs back together with spaces.

Alternatively you can get the array and split/join it from within the function, if you always will want to get the data from the same source.

Comment: This looks like ti will work exactly right! Where do I put var pigString in the function?

Comment: Here's a fiddle with an example usage.  Exactly how you use it depends on what you're doing with the string and where you're getting the original from. http://jsfiddle.net/eSgC2/2/

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript's split() method.  In this case, you can take do `var 
arrayOfWords = thingWeCase.split(" ")`
  This splits the string into an array of strings, with the split point being at each space.  Then you can easily go through each element in the resulting array.

Comment: Great! I see what you're doing there. Once I split the array with that new variable, how do I send each piece of the array through the function?

Comment: well thats up to you.  I would make a for loop and go through each element, performing the pig latin method on each element.  In the end you can concatenate them together using `var sentence = str1 + " " + str2...`

Comment: @AlanJosephSylvestre https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: I think you want map + join.  See my answer for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Write a function that calls your single-word function in a loop:

```
function loopPigLatin(wordString) {
   words = wordString.split(" ");
   for( var i in words)
     words[i] = wholePigLatin(words[i]);
   return words.join(" ");
}
```

Of course, to call it like this, you'll want to make a slight change to your original function:

```
function wholePigLatin(thingWeCase) {
     // everything after the first line
     return newWord2; // add this at the end
}
```

And then call `loopPigLatin` like this:

```
document.getElementById("outputBox").innerHTML = loopPigLatin(document.getElementById("isLeaper").value);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just match words with regexp and replace them with callback:

```
var toPigLatin = (function () {
    var convertMatch = function (m) {
        var index = m.search(/[aeiou]/);
        if (index > 0) {
            return m.substr(index) + m.substr(0,index) + 'ay';
        }
        return m + 'way';
    };
    return function (str) {
        return str.toLowerCase().replace(/(\w+)/g, convertMatch);
    };
}());

console.info(toPigLatin("lorem ipsum dolor.")); // --> oremlay ipsumway olorday.
```